# Using svelte with events in ag-grid custom tool panel

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, svelte

I´ve a working custom tool panel in ag-grid. The problem is that events like onclick don´t work inside the custom tool panel. I´ve put the function in every place i can think of but i always get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: externalFilterChanged is not defined at
>   HTMLButtonElement.onclick

I´ve opend a enterprise ticket with ag-grid and attached the code you see on github. But they tell me it is svelte related and they don´t support svelte.

Please have a look if you have a deeper understanding of svelte than i have.
[Code on Github](https://github.com/benjamin79/test_svelte_ag_grid)

I can get it to work by putting the function in window. But that doesn´t seem like a good solution.

thanks

Comment: Your custom tool panel should be a component written in svelte itself and then you won't have any problems calling your on change handler.

Comment: @Andreas_D thanks, i´ve tried that as well. But it only works when i use context="module" in the script tag. Otherwise ag-grid doesn´t take the component. Any idea?

Comment: @Andreas_D ag-grid expects the html to be inside a javascript function.